# Main domain and sub domain

Tags: server, dns, subdomain

I have a domain and sub-domain each one on the different server.
I want to know is it possible that the down-time of the main domain effects the functionality of sub-domain which is on the different server.

Comment: This question cannot be answered without knowing what is on those servers, and what the relationship between them is. If they are both servers hosting static websites, they don't rely one another at all. If one hosts a dynamic site, whereas the other hosts a backend API, the two rely extremely one another. More information must be provided.

Comment: there is no any relationship on these sites. I have just created the sub-domain on main-domain's Cpanel and the main-domain mostly is down and I thought maybe it effect my sub-domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both your domain (example.com) and your subdomain (sub.example.com) are independent from each other and i assume dont share the same IP, downtimes from example.com dont affect sub.example.com in any way.

My answer is based on the information you provided.

Comment: Thank you for your help.